# Processing data with javascript and showing in HTML with Angular.JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Currently I work with processing user data from Facebook.

We have the client-side which is on a site other than the server, where the data is processed and saved.

It works like this:

```
1) The user enters the site and gives access to the application. (working)
2) We send the data to the server. (POST) (working)
3) We take the data on the server. (GET) (working)
4) We process the data to appear in HTML on the server. (not working)
5) We decid what data we want to save. (working)
6) We re-save the data (update) (PUT). (ready to work)
```

As you can see, the problem is showing the data with Angular.

```
(function (){
    var app = angular.module('confirmados', []);

    app.controller('ListaController', function (){
        this.items = peoples;
    });

    var peoples = [
        {   id: 121321231121,
            name: 'somename',
            email: 'someemail@hotmail.com'
        },
        {   id: 32111131,
            name: 'somename',
            email: 'someemail@hotmail.com'
        }
etc
etc
etc

    ];






    var host = 'http://localhost';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: host + '/reservations',
        success:function(data){

How can I assign the data that is coming here to 'peoples' array?


        },
    });
```

And this is the HTML.

```
<tr ng-repeat="list in list.peoples" class="reservations">
                            <td> <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
                            <td> {{list.id}} </td>
                            <td> {{list.name}} </td>
                            <td> {{list.email}} </td>
</tr>
```

---

I need to pull the data that is coming in the AJAX request and assign it to this array, then the data will appear in the HTML.

```
    var peoples = [
        {   id: 121321231121,
            name: 'somename',
            email: 'someemail@hotmail.com'
        },
        {   id: 32111131,
            name: 'somename',
            email: 'someemail@hotmail.com'
        }
etc
etc
etc

    ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see comments inside code snippet

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ListaController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.peoples = [];
  
    // put proper endpoint here
    var host = 'https://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q=kaizers+orchestra';

    $http.get(host).then(onSucess, onError);

    function onSucess(response) {
      
        console.log(response)
        
        //replace 'response.data.tracks' with 'response' or 'response.data'
        $scope.peoples = response.data.tracks;
    };

    function onError() {
        alert("Can't get data");
    }



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
    <table ng-controller="ListaController">
        <tr ng-repeat="list in peoples" class="reservations">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" />
            </td>
            <td>{{list.id}}</td>
            <td>{{list.name}}</td>
            <td>{{list.email}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: sss, can u please answer me something??? how can i transform the data into a json object?.. assuming it is a string..

Comment: @Nescau please see here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson

Comment: I realized that you are not using in the HTML ng-controller = "ListController as list", just "ListController".. can u please tell me why? @sss

Comment: @Nescau you can use both styles. Last time more and more people start using Controller as something convention so you know, depends on you which style do you prefer